# How does Google create mobile friendly fixed backgrounds and parallax content in iframe?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, ads

My current test involves an intersectionobserver that uses iframe postMessage with current scroll position in order to translate3d background image in the iframe. But this creates a lot of jitter, a potential delay when in production and I can see more issues with this approach. From what I understand playing around in the web developer tool by Google, the ads are using parallax in order to make content responsive to the scroll position, but does Google rely on postMessage for this, or what do they do in order to make a smooth experience for fixed backgrounds and content responding to scroll events in parent window?

```
Some code example
```

[DEMO](https://fiddle.jshell.net/x208n5fy/4/show/) || [CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/x208n5fy/4/)

[image: Jitter]

As far as I understand, the component used is called Parallax and is available in [Google Web Designer](https://support.google.com/displayvideo/answer/9020683?hl=en)

[image: Her face is turning as you scroll (series of images changing based on yPosition)]
[image: Dial and background image changing based on scroll position]
[image: Fixed position background]

Regarding the fixed background, I know that iOS doesn't support background-attachment: fixed, why it has to be some JS based functionality. And then triggered by the intersectionobserver in the parent window I believe. If Google ads at all rely on the parent window to provide any information, or if everything is managed from inside the iframe - I don't know. But I would like to hear if anyone knows about these techniques and the work behind it, cause it seems like something very simple, yet very unachievable for mere mortals like me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What an interesting question! I would like to start with your last gif.

#### Gif #3

> Regarding the fixed background, I know that iOS doesn't support `background-attachment: fixed`, why it has to be some JS based functionality.

Even if IOS would support `background-attachment: fixed` this wouldn't work, because this property is only for background images. It also isn't JS (at least not necessarily), as you can just do it with CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
}

.spacer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: transparent;
}

.background-scroller {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="background-scroller">
  This could be anything
</div>
```

I am aware that on some sites those ads change for each "spacer", but this is also possible with CSS only by using `position: sticky`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
}

.spacer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: transparent;
}

.background-scroller {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vH;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: left;
}

.section-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <div class="background-scroller">
    This is one thing
  </div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>

  <div class="background-scroller">
    And this is something completely else
  </div>

  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>

  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Each site does it differently and a lot of them use the intersection observer API, but my point is, that sometimes a bit of simple CSS does the job. So it is not necessarily JS! Those are some legitimate ways to do this.

---

#### Gif #2, Gif #1

Those effects are a bit more complex.

Cross-origin restrictions are a big (but necessary) bummer. Your parent frame has very restricted access to the iframe and the other way around. This leaves us with just a couple of [properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_script_API_access) we can use.

If you inspect the iframe element, you might have noticed, that they use a `data-is-safeframe` attribute. I copied such an element and removed every unimportant attribute.

```html
<iframe src="" data-is-safeframe="true" sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation"></iframe>
```

What is SafeFrame? Well, the [SafeFrame API](https://www.iab.com/guidelines/safeframe/) is developed by IAB (Interactive Advertising Bureau) and basically allows communication between the advertiser and the ad provider. To know exactly what they use this API for is probably impossible to find out, if you are not a Google Developer.

There is only one modern way to communicate with cross-origin `iframes`: `postMessage()`.
Yes, they also use SafeFrame, but I think this is not meant for things like this. There is no way (for Google too), to break this rule. To be sure, I did some testing (which was really unnecessary if I think about it) and all of my tests failed.

---

> But this creates a lot of jitter

This surprised me as `postMessage` shouldn't be that slow. I made a small example with JSFiddle, because SO made some weird stuff with my `iframe`.

- Here is the page that will be displayed inside the `iframe`: [Click](//fiddle.jshell.net/aetgq3jz/3/show/) or [Code](https://jsfiddle.net/aetgq3jz/3/)
- Here is the page that will display the `iframe` and send the `postMessage()` (scroll down the page (not the `iframe`)): [Click](//fiddle.jshell.net/67Ltcxdh/1/show/) or [Code](https://jsfiddle.net/67Ltcxdh/1/).

If you take a look at the console, you will notice that `postMessage` is definetly fast enough to handle fast triggering events like `scroll`. You can also notice it because of the "disco `iframe`".

So to be honest, I think the fault is on your site.

---

#### Conclusion

I don't know the exact way Google has accomplished this. However, there is only one possible way I can think of: `postMessage` - an approach you already chose. This means that, if there is no other way, this must be the way Google used.

Your performance issues must be a fault on your side.

---

So this is just my opinion. There might be technologies and ways I didn't think of. I find this question very interesting and, if my solution isn't right, I want to know the correct answer! So feel free to correct me.

---

## Edit #1

After a lot of time-consuming investigation, I have finally found the solution from creditable sources: in a way, from Google itself. But also from various sites that I found, which take advantage of such an effect.

#### Short answer

It basically is like I explained at **Gif #3**.

#### Long answer

Such an ad has different names: **Interscroller**, **Flying carpet**, **sticky ad**, there might be more but those are the ones I've come across.

What I've found out is that ads are often written and implemented with [AMP](https://amp.dev/) (*Accelerated Mobile Pages*), published by Google.

After finally having found a site that uses a *Flying Carpet Ad*, I could inspect it and found the following:

[image]

This confirmed my findings. They use AMP! But not only them, I've come across different sites which use the same technique.

Let's analyze the HTML structure. The part we focus on is the `<amp-fx-flying-carpet>` and its first parent `<div class="amp-article-ad>` until the `<iframe>`.

The basic structure with all the unnecessary stuff removed looks like the following:

```html
<div class="amp-article-ad">
  ::before
  <amp-fx-flying-carpet>
    <div class="i-amphtml-fx-flying-carpet-clip">
      <div class="i-amphtml-fx-flying-carpet-container">
        <amp-ad class="amp-article-ad-element i-amphtml-layout-fixed i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout">
          <div fallback></div>
          <amp-analytics></amp-analytics>
          <iframe></iframe>
        </amp-ad>
      </div>
    </div>
  </amp-fx-flying-carpet>
</div>
```

If we reduce this even further by removing all wrappers that are unnecessary, the structure looks like this:

```html
<div class="amp-article-ad">
  <amp-fx-flying-carpet>
    <div class="i-amphtml-fx-flying-carpet-container">
      <amp-ad>
        <iframe></iframe>
      </amp-ad>
    </div>
  </amp-fx-flying-carpet>
</div>
```

Let's start at the beginning. `<div class="amp-article-ad">` is just the wrapper for the ad and contains `<amp-fx-flying-carpet>`. The size of `<div class="amp-article-ad">` and `<amp-fx-flying-carpet>` is the same and is the window we can see the ad through:

[image]

Now comes the important part! `<div class="i-amphtml-fx-flying-carpet-container">` is the wrapper of `<amp-ad>` and it's size is bigger then that of it's wrapper `<amp-fx-flying-carpet>` (the size of the ad to be presize), which already indicates that some CSS property took it out of the flow. Examples for some properties are:

- `float: left`
- `float: right`
- `position: fixed`
- `position: absolute`
- ...

And you probably see where I am going. The CSS properties of `<div class="i-amphtml-fx-flying-carpet-container">` are:

[image]

There we have it: `position: fixed`!

The size of `<amp-ad>` is that of the ad, which makes sense, since it contains the iframe, which contains the ad.

[image]
[image]

The `<iframe>` obviously just contains the ad.

---

So we have the outer wrappers which function as the window we can see through. Inside this window are containers, which are taken out of the flow by adding `position: fixed`. Those fixed containers contain the `<iframe>`, which contains the ad.

---

Convince yourself! Here is the official AMP documentation with examples:
https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-fx-flying-carpet/#flying-carpet-for-ads

The structure is pretty much the same. Of course, I made a small example, using the same technique:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.flying-carpet-wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.amp-ad-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

iframe {
  border: 0;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>

<div class="flying-carpet-wrapper"> <!--<amp-fx-flying-carpet>-->
 <div class="amp-ad-wrapper"> <!--<div class="i-amphtml-fx-flying-carpet-container">-->
   <div class="amp-ad"> <!--<amp-ad>-->
      <iframe src="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerated_Mobile_Pages"></iframe>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
```

Comment: Your observations are great. My reference to the Jitter is whenever I use `postMessage` to send the scrollY position to the iframe. Looking at the code example for gif #3 I can't see how these are implemented inside the iframe. As the fixed background is inside the iframe but relative to the parent window. Considering that the background stays fixed relative to the parent window dimensions and not the iframe itself. Using an iFrame with the CSS example you gave, the iframe content doesn't stay fixed to parent scroll: https://jsfiddle.net/Lyxoc17k/2/

Comment: _"Looking at the code example for gif #3 I can't see how these are implemented inside the iframe. As the fixed background is inside the iframe but relative to the parent window."_ - This is not correct. It isn't the content inside the iframe that is fixed. It is the `iframe` itself that got fixed to the page.

If I understand you correctly, you try to fix the content of the `iframe` by sending the `scrollY` position via `postMessage`. Yes, this will create jitter.

Comment: _"Using an iFrame with the CSS example you gave, the iframe content doesn't stay fixed to parent scroll: [jsfiddle.net/Lyxoc17k/2](jsfiddle.net/Lyxoc17k/2)"_ - I was trying to show, that `postMessage` is fast enough to (theoratically) update an image to get some sort of animation, like in Gif #1.

But now, that I understand what you mean with _Jitter_ and your approach, here is an iframe that does stay fixed to the parent scroll: [https://jsfiddle.net/wrub3nh5/](https://jsfiddle.net/wrub3nh5/)

Comment: I just added `position: fixed`. That's what I meant with _"It isn't the content inside the iframe that is fixed. It is the iframe itself that got fixed to the page."_ I don't send the scroll position via `postMessage` to update the `iframe` content, I just fix the `iframe` itself. Fixing stuff to the page is what [`position: fixed`](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fixed_menu) is for.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/x208n5fy/4/ - This shows the jitter I am experiencing. - just demo: https://fiddle.jshell.net/x208n5fy/4/show/

Comment: This is expected behavior, due to a delay in `postMessage`. But you still use `postMessage` for this. **You don't need `postMessage` at all** for this project. I removed the borders of the `iframe` and gave the rest a background-color. This is what **your** approach looks like afterwards: https://jsfiddle.net/jgk6xfd0/  -  You can still the jitter.

Comment: What you did was to send the offset and adjust the `iframe` **content** accordingly. This is not the way to go. Instead, **fix the whole iframe**! This is the result: https://jsfiddle.net/mgdu5nfq/

Comment: I think you can see what I've done if you take a look at [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mLpb2zhg/)

Comment: See - I get that part... But when you embed a Google ad inside an article like in Gif #3, the iframe is not positioned fixed - but its content is. This is the trick that I am interested in understanding. The iframe is positioned relative to the article content following as the user scrolls the content, but the actual content of the iframe is fixed according to the viewport as the user scrolls.

Comment: Mmh I was able to get an ad like this and they did it in my way. But yes, I am sure that the ads you describe exist. I will look into that.

Comment: I did some further digging... Found something rather interesting.. Looking at this: https://support.google.com/displayvideo/answer/9020683?hl=en, I dug a little further and found this article: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/performant-parallaxing... I will continue my search.

Comment: This is interesting - I have created two versions using perspective property. https://jsfiddle.net/dhjmtur1/1/show https://jsfiddle.net/dhjmtur1/2/show. The first one embeds an iframe which `translates` the Y position according to postMessage info whereas the scond one changes the scroll position. Translate still creates a lot of jitter, so have to find a more performant way to implement it

Comment: As I found out, Google ads use AMP HTML and can be implemented with one tag. https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-sticky-ad/ I am trying to find out how that works. But am currently on mobile so this will be done later.

Comment: Brilliant! I realised overflow hidden on HTML in second version gives the effect desired. No jitter. https://jsfiddle.net/Ly1pjghv/1/ Still needs some work though.

Comment: Looks great, but I'm starting to think, that this is not the way they've done this. `postMessage` is asynchronous and will **always** have a delay.

Comment: Exactly.. The core reason I opened this question :/

Comment: Done! I've found the answer @Dimser Let me know if you have any questions!